# how to get and manipulate CBitmap information

Tags: c++, mfc, multidimensional-array, dimension, cbitmap

I am a total newbie to c++ and non the less MFC so bare with my questions please.. i have been using MatLab throughout college to do image processing
HERE IS THE QUESTION:

I have already read a `.bmp` image and stored it into a `CBitmap` object, but i have no idea how to get information from this object like (Width,Length) in pixels.
In matlab i used to get a matrix when i read an image and i could easily apply filters to this matrix.

the image was read like

```
[1   3  123  13]
[12  33 34   14]
[131 46 32   67]
```

I could read value of individual pixels and do arithmetic operations to change it.
Can I do the same with a `CBitmap` object?
or should I read the image into something else like 2D arrays or something?

Answer (score 2):

Your first question is clear: how to get dimensions of the image in pixels.
Please try this:

```
CBitmap cbmp;
//load your bitmap here into the cbmp 
BITMAP aBmp;
cbmp.GetBitmap(&aBmp);
int imgWidthInPixels = aBmp.bmWidth;
int imgHeightInPixels = aBmp.bmHeight;
```